# How can I see if a marker is with in a circle marker?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, leaflet

I need to check every 5 seconds if a marker(user) is now contained in a circleMarker(loc)

```
function updateLocation(){
            if(!isSet){clearInterval(start)}else{
                user.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
                if(loc.getBounds().contains(new L.LatLng(lat, lng))){
                    document.getElementById('setButton').style.background = 'purple'
                    soundAlarm();
                    isSet = false;
                }           
            }
        }
```

Above is the current code I have, which is called by this:

`var start = setInterval(updateLocation, 5000);`

Thanks in advance, Ed.

Comment: And what is happening instead?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately. It just act's as if it can't see the marker in the circleMarker.

Comment: `loc.getBounds().contains(new L.LatLng(lat, lng))` Evaluates to false.

Comment: var start = setInterval(updateLocation(), 5000); might be better [note added parentheses]

Comment: That will only call the function once as opposed to doing it multiple times.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for explaining. Is there a reason for doing new L.LatLng(lat, lng) 2 lines in a row as opposed to just saying contains(L)? But that would not cause the error. It is a little hard to diagnose this without seeing where lat and lng are coming from. But I guess I will leave that to people more expert. Good luck. (p.s. Are you the same Ed Lynch I had for math ed at U. Mn. long ago?)

Comment: Thanks, also afraid not, I'm in the UK, never been to the states.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy, it is basically impossible to help you with that problem without knowing where lat, lng and loc come from. After all, from the code, we could think it evaluates false all the time because the marker never goes inside your loc. Could you share a jsfiddle so that we can see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to do [geofencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence), but in a weird way. Why rely on the drawn appearance of `CircleMarker`s when all you want is to know if the distance from the user to something is less than a threshold (the `CircleMarker` radius)?

Just use the `distance` method of `L.Map`:

```
var guardedLocation = L.latLng(...);
var thresholdDistance = 100;    // In meters
var start;

function updateLocation(){
    var userPosition = L.latLng(lat, lng);
    user.setLatLng(userPosition);

    if(map.distance(userPosition, guardedLocation) <= thresholdDistance) {
        document.getElementById('setButton').style.background = 'purple'
        soundAlarm();
        isSet = false;
        clearInterval(start);
    }
}

start = setInterval(updateLocation, 5000);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mark your answer as correct sooner, I've been really busy lately and only just got back to the project. Thanks though, that solution was perfect. `metresPerPixel = 40075016.686 * Math.abs(Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat * 180/Math.PI)) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()+8);` I found that code useful to convert between pixels and meters by the way if anybody else has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your `loc` variable is really an `L.circleMarker`, please realize that by definition a *marker* is a point / place, i.e. it does not have any *area*, hence no *bounds*. You probably meant to use an `L.circle` for `loc` in the first place.

In Leaflet 0.x (e.g. version 0.7.7), the `L.circleMarker` inherits from `L.circle`, therefore it does have a [`.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-getbounds) method, even though it is meaningless. Actually it returns a null area (southWest coordinates equal northEast coordinates equal the marker position).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y63u5utf/2/

So your code would actually evaluate to `true` *iif* the user location is *exactly* the same as your `loc`.

In Leaflet 1.x (e.g. current version 1.0.1), this inconsistency has been corrected, and `L.circleMarker` no longer has the `.getBounds()` method.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y63u5utf/1/

(zoom in and out to see the radius of the red circle marker adjusting to keep the same size in pixels, until at high zoom, the marker is out of it. Whereas the blue circle has a radius which scales according to the zoom, since it represents an actual length; therefore it always contains (or not) the marker)